# SQL Server: why variable works outside IF

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have trigger where on top of it I declare

```
DECALRE @variable VARCHAR(100) = ' '
```

And then below it, I have this sample IF statement

```
IF UPDATE ([data])
BEGIN
SET @variable = 'Data change'
END
```

And then insert with this @variable on the end of the trigger.
My problem is that even though [data] remains unchanged it inserts 'Data change' into DB instead of ''

Comment: Show us your full SQL, not just snippets

Comment: Whole trigger is huge, i just have to expand it and I guess those snippets are essential to explain my problem

Comment: Then provide us with an [mre], as that behaviour doesn't occur as you describe: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7c6be68f9a43dad19c0e2ef52164b468)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation of [UPDATE - Trigger Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)  states clearly:

> UPDATE() returns TRUE **regardless** of whether an INSERT or UPDATE attempt is successful.

Please check:

```
UPDATE t SET id = 2 WHERE id = 1;  /*if block is not executed */
-- 1 rows affected
```

and(even though there is no real change on `data` column):

```
UPDATE t SET id = 1, data = data WHERE id = 2; /*if block is executed */
-- Data change
-- 1 rows affected
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=511d4781c7973264e605e14b29db920f)**

Comment: It's not about if insert is executed, because it always is. My problem is that variable  initially declared as empty string is filled with string provided inside If block even tho this if is not true 100% times and then ' ' is suppouse to be inserted instead of 'Data change' from inside IF block

Comment: `even tho this if is not true 100% times` - please provide reproducible case. In current form this question is vague.

Comment: @xxx_kuba_xxx `UPDATE(col)` function check only if the column was part of update, not if content of column has changed, so the condition is **true**.

Comment: I have other columns in table, it's made like : id, address, name, attributes, data, and each of these columns has its own if update() block inside this trigger, but only in if update([data]) there's SET @ variable = 'Data change', so i'm looking for solution that if not [data] changed, but for example [address] then @ variable remains ' ' as it's declared like that on top of trigger and only being changed if [data] is updated

Comment: Okay, now I got it, can I ask for tip how I can achieve logic as described above?

Comment: @xxx_kuba_xxx `how I can achieve logic as described above` - this is outside scope of this question. You will have to perform data comparison on multiple columns plus make sure you handle nulls properly(special tables inserted/deleted). One more tip: in SQL Server trigger fires per "statement" not per row.

Comment: Thank You then, maybe yet someone will notice this discussion here and add sth. I'll accept Your answer on evening.

Comment: @xxx_kuba_xxx Just compare data between `inserted` and `deleted` tables - if values differ, set your variable. And once again - trigger fires for entire updateable set, not per single row.

Comment: It isn't just that `update()` only checks whether the column was part of the update, the value actually *is* updated. That is to say, the former value is removed, and the new value takes its place. Whether or not these two values are the same is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

As the others suggested, `Update()` is always true

So you may try a solution like the following

```
DECLARE @variable VARCHAR(100) = 'initial data'

if (Select Count(*) 
    From [<TblToBeUpdated>] t 
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON t.[<PK>] = i.[<PK>]
    INNER JOIN Inserted d ON t.[<PK>] = d.[<PK>]
    WHERE t.[<ColToBeUpdated>] <> i.[<ColOfQuery>] OR
        t.[<ColToBeUpdated>] <> d.[<ColOfQuery>]
    ) > 0
Begin
    SET @variable = 'Data change'
End
```

see the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=0ac93f669a58393fa2552d3b6c043e91)